# How to subclass Hibernate entity class effectively replacing the parent?

Tags: hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1, hibernate-4.x

Given the following scenario:

- A project using a framework
- The framework defines basic entity classes (used for logging, user management etc.)
- The project has application specific entity classes.

I want to subclass a framework class in a way that does not need changes to the framework code nor the framework specific database schema (apart from any constraints that maybe introduced by additional mappings).

Here is a simplified framework class:

```
package com.example.parent;

@Entity
@Table("entities")
public class ExampleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Integer id;

    protected String name;

}
```

And the application specific extension:

```
package com.example.child;

@Entity
public class ExampleEntity extends com.example.parent.ExampleEntity {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn
    protected Set<OtherEntity> otherEntities;    

}
```

As you can see this just adds an additional mapping to an application specific entity class.
This won't work with Hibernate 4.3.11 out-of-the-box. It will try to create a discriminator column (`dtype`) which is not desired and IMHO not required here.

I want this to be as transparent as possible (i.e. without changing anything on the framework side) and without any additional manual mapping/casting in the application. Effectively, I want to trick Hibernate into loading only instances of `com.example.child.ExampleEntity` without the framework even noticing.

**TL;DR**

How to trick Hibernate into loading entities from the `entities` table as instances of `com.example.child.ExampleEntity`?

Answer (score 0):

You can used `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` on the parent class. You can find an example [here](http://www.dineshonjava.com/p/implementing-inheritance-in-hibernate.html).

So it would work with

```
package com.example.parent;

@Entity
@Table("entities")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ExampleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Integer id;

    protected String name;

}
```

So you can join any other table to children or parent

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) is the official documentation about inheritance mapping.

Comment: I think the origional question said how to get it to work _without_ changing the framework classes, but I think you are suggesting to modify the framework class by adding the @Inheritance annotation.